# Convert array to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

I have an Array `var cars = [2,3,..]` which holds a few integers.
I've added a few values to the array, but I now need to send this array to a page via jQuery's `.get` method. How can I convert it to a JSON object for sending?

Comment: Just double-checking: is the array you want to send to the page a JavaScript array or is it on the server?

Comment: it's a Javascript array, I will be sending it to a Python script and Python will use the JSON string and work with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json/71512964#71512964

Answer (score 792, accepted):

Script for backward-compatibility: 
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

And call:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

**Note:** *The JSON object is now part of most modern web browsers (IE 8 & above). See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/json) for full listing. Credit goes to: @Spudley for his comment below*

Comment: This works, does jQuery have a function like this? I'd prefer not to attach another js file if jQuery has a function already.

Comment: jQuery has the implementation of JSON.parse in 1.4.1, but not JSON.stringify... If you minifiy json2.js its <3k I think.

Comment: Yeah I was suprised jQuery didn't have this built in too

Comment: Got json2.js down to 3,334 bytes. This will have to do for the time being. Thanks JonoW and gnarf

Comment: for anyone still reading this answer, it's worth pointing out that all modern browsers include the `JSON` object as standard, which means that **you don't need this script** unless you're planning to support older browsers like IE7 or Firefox 3.0. See [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/json) for the support chart.

Comment: @Spudley, this answer helped me as Mongo Console uses JS but it didn't like printing an array.

Comment: It's worth pointing out you can do this in a browser console:  var a = [paste]; JSON.stringify(a)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json/71512964#71512964

Comment: @Spudley it would be nice to add a context, e.g. SQLite does not support JSONs directly and you still have to store them as strings. `FormData` also does not support JSON but only a form element. `XMLHttpRequest.send` also does not support JSON directly. So the only thing that really commonly supports JSON is JS code itself and `jQuery.ajax` in `data`.

Comment: The best answer.

Answer (score 77):

I made it that way:

if I have:

```
var jsonArg1 = new Object();
    jsonArg1.name = 'calc this';
    jsonArg1.value = 3.1415;
var jsonArg2 = new Object();
    jsonArg2.name = 'calc this again';
    jsonArg2.value = 2.73;

var pluginArrayArg = new Array();
    pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg1);
    pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg2);
```

to convert pluginArrayArg (which is pure javascript array) into JSON array:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pluginArrayArg))
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is not needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json/71512964#71512964

Answer (score 62):

Wow, seems it got a lot easier nowadays... 3 ways you can do it:

```
json = { ...array };

json = Object.assign({}, array);

json = array.reduce((json, value, key) => { json[key] = value; return json; }, {});
```

Comment: `jsonString = JSON.stringify({ ...array })`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json/71512964#71512964

Answer (score 26):

## What do you want ?

If you want json  **String**

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify(JsArray);
```

If you want json **Object**

```
var JsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JsArray));
```

---

More details!

> Using `JSON.stringify()`, we convert the JavaScript array to Json string. And using `JSON.parse()`, we convert Json string to a Json object.

Comment: the modern answer

Answer (score 14):

One other way could be this:

```
        var json_arr = {};
        json_arr["name1"] = "value1";
        json_arr["name2"] = "value2";
        json_arr["name3"] = "value3";

        var json_string = JSON.stringify(json_arr);
```

Comment: `json_arr` in your code is no array but an object.

Answer (score 12):

I decided to use the json2 library and I got an error about “cyclic data structures”.

I got it solved by telling json2 how to convert my complex object. Not only it works now but also I have included only the fields I need. Here is how I did it:

```
OBJ.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
       var returnObj = new Object();
       returnObj.devid = this.devid;
       returnObj.name = this.name;
       returnObj.speed = this.speed;
       returnObj.status = this.status;
       return returnObj;
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

Or try defining the array as an object. (var cars = {};) Then there is no need to convert to json. This might not be practical in your example but worked well for me.

Answer (score 10):

because my array was like below:
and I used .push function to create it dynamically

```
my_array = ["234", "23423"];
```

The only way I converted my array into json is

```
json = Object.assign({}, my_array);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Shortest

To generate valid json from array of integers use

```
let json = `[${cars}]`
```

for more general arrays use JSON.stringify(cars) (for object with circular references use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798003/860099))

```js
let cars = [1,2,3]; cars.push(4,5,6);

let json = `[${cars}]`;

console.log(json);
console.log(JSON.parse(json)); // json validation
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have only 1 object like the one you asked, the following will work.

```
var x = [{'a':'b'}];
var b= JSON.stringify(x);
var c = b.substring(1,b.length-1);
JSON.parse(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an array to JSON using the Object.assign function. The main issue that I hit with that is that Javascript arrays have a zero based integer key, which in turn allows to access the data in the array.

```
let fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana']
document.write(fruits[0])
```

Returns:

**Apple**

When you convert the array to JSON, you get

```
{"0": "Apple", "1: "Banana"}
```

JSON objects on the contrary usually contain arbitrary keys, such as:

{
"some_key": "some value",
"other_key: "some other value"
}

Happily, you can create a list of items, which works pretty much as an array and then use Object.assign as if it was an array, then convert the output to a JSON object

```
var items = {};
items["some_key"]="some value";
items["other_key"]="some other value";
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, items)) 
const json_obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

The advantage of working with item lists is that you don't have to deal with the JSON data as a string or quotes, commas etc... You can instead just manage the item object filling data in or removing it. When you are done you just convert the item variable to a JSON object and do whatever you need to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

With your cars array: var cars = [2,3,..]. You can use for loop like this

```
    var carArray = new Array();  

    for(var c in cars) {
      var jsonObj = new Object();
      jsonObj.car_id = cars[c];
      carArray.push(jsonObj);
    }
```