# Issue on passing a checkbox set to an AppEngine script through jQuery Ajax/Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-app-engine

I have a set of checkboxes with multiple choice allowed. I parse the set this way:

```
if ($("input[name='route_day']:checked").length > 0) {
    $("input[name='route_day']:checked").each(function(){
     if(this.value != null)
  route_days_hook.push(this.value); 
  });
  dataTrap.route_days = $.JSON.encode(route_days_hook);
}
```

...and pull the whole `dataTrap` to an AppEngine Python script via jQuery ajax. However, the Python script just bugs. If i change `dataTrap.route_days` value to a string instead of the JSON encoded object, everything works fine.
My question is: how can i pass a checkbox set to the script using Ajax and still be able to iterate over it on the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
 dataTrap.route_days = $.parseJSON(route_days_hook);
```

**EDIT**

if that didn't work, maybe it's because you are trying to convert an array object to JSON...

try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-javascript-array-to-json) instead.