# Capturing form data: variables or array?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with about 20 input fields. I capture values of these fields, then do some calculations and output several values.

Is there a preferred/recommended way of capturing form data? Currently I store every form field into a separate variable. I was wondering if storing it to an array would be a better and more effective approach.

I'm quite new to Javascript and programming in general, trying to learn the best practices.

Comment: You may want to try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best practice on this depends on what I have to do with the data. If I do not need to loop through it, or send it to another page/service, then there's nothing wrong with individual scoped-variables.

If I need to loop at all, I commonly use an array or object to loop through.

If I have to pass it to another page/service, I make one object variable to encapsulate the rest of them, so I can "stringify" it to JSON and parse back to an object on the other end.

Just my opinion,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the third approach - just use the data from the form without storing it anywhere.

First check the correctness, once it is considered correct just use what you have.

Comment: In the calculations I'm doing I need to use some of that data in several different formulas so storing them into a variable/array seemed like the right approach to me. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I would put the form in variable, then use something like form['value'] in calculations. 
For the variables that are used more often you could put them in the variable. Putting them in the array wouldn't give you much benefit, form is a sort of array, so no need to add additional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should always assign the attribute "name=..." to an input element, so you can use something like:

```
var form = document.forms['form'];
var email = form['email'];
email = do something
```

if you use javascript... if you use jquery it's simple $('input[name="email"]') = do something

I prefer this way because you can call variables by name, not by number, for example "form[0] that corresponds to input[name="email"]".

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing but having 20 - 30 variables seemed a little bit overwhelming to me so I was wondering if there is a better way to work with the form data.

Comment: I suggest you to continue on this way, then you can check all them with some functions. If you have 2 or more input that need the same control you haven't to write 20 functions but just 1 for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the associative properties of `array`s in JavaScript to get the benefits of unique field names and OOP:**

```
var formModel = new Array();

formModel['myField'] = getMyFieldValue(); // make 'myField' index to any object
```

Then you can do things like:

- `formModel['myField'] // get the value`
- `formModel.length; // number of fields added`
- `for (entry in formModel) { /* loop thru entries */ }`
- `formModel.sort([compareFunction]) // custom sort`
- `formModel = []; // clear the model`
- [Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-javascript-array-to-json)
- Any of these [Array<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) conveniences.

Just one approach, but arrays in JS are extremely versatile and IMO underused objects in JS.