# Passing javascript array to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp, servlets

I have looked previous questions on this topic on SO, but my problem is not solved yet.

I am passing the array from javascript to servlet.

JavaScript Code:

```
var action = new Array();
function getProtAcionValues(rowNo,columnCount)
{
    for(var j=0;j<columnCount;j++)
    {
        action[j] =  document.getElementById('textActions'+rowNo+''+j).value;
        alert(action[j]);
    }
}
```

Servlet Code:

```
String actions[] = request.getParameterValues("action[]");
if(actions!=null)
for(int i=0;i<actions.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print(" Action: "+actions);
}
else
    System.out.println("Action is null");
```

Using above code I am getting message **"Action is null"**.

And if I try

```
String actions[] = request.getParameterNames("action[]");
```

I am getting Syntax error:

```
The method getParameterNames() in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Please let me know if there is something wrong in code.

Comment: Where is the HTML or JavaScript code that calls the servlet?

Comment: Can you post the code of how are you sending the action array to the servlet...

Comment: <form name="form2" method="post" action="ServletName">
<input type="submit" value="Update" id="btnUpdate" onclick="passValues()" name="btn">

Comment: Can you post the code of how are you sending the action array to the servlet.i mean how to set action[] to request object,please let me know it is very useful for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can just simply get the array with the name of the array...

**String actions[] = request.getParameterValues("action");**

Comment: Tomcat isn't recognizing the parameter unless I add brackets to the end of the name, i.e. ("action[]")..

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a java array as a parameter, as it is an structure. The best way is to serialize it into an string object like a jSon. You can use [JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-javascript-array-to-json). Simple and efficient. As you can serialize in the server also, it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Javascript array variable with form action to send values to servlet, and then use

```
String[] darray=request.getParameterValues("variable name used with link");
```