# How to send a javascript array to Java servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Hello people I'm doing a web application some orthodox, my method is AJAX using java and javascript.

And I asking me if is possible set a array from javascript to Servlet.

Comment: Possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099508/passing-javascript-array-to-servlet

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible!

```
var test = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'get', 
    url: 'someurl',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { 
      test: JSON.stringify(test) 
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

And in servlet:

```
String json = request.getParameter("test");
```