# Send array in ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I'm trying to send an array from **JavaScript** to **PHP** with the `$.post()` method of Jquery.

I've tried `jQuery.serialize()`, `jQuery.serializeArray()`, `JSON.stringify()` and all of them didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$.post("ajax/"+action+"_xml.php",{'array': array},function(data){console.log(data);});
```

the array looks like this :

```
array["type"]
array["vars"]["name"]
array["vars"]["email"]
```

array["vars"] has more than 2 elements.

The result in my php `$_POST` variable is an empty array (length 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following structure on the data which you pass:

**Javascript:**

```
var DTO = { 
    type: [1,2,3],
    vars: {  
        name: 'foo',
        email: 'foo@bar.com'
    }
};

var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(DTO); 

// will result in:
//{"type":[1,2,3],"vars":{"name":"foo","email":"foo@bar.com"}} 

$.post("ajax/"+action+"_xml.php",{'DTO': stringifiedData },function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

**PHP:**

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$DTO = $_POST['DTO'];

if(isset($DTO))
{
    $assocResult = json_decode($DTO, true);
    var_dump($assocResult); //do stuff with $assocResult here
}
```

Passing `true` as the second argument to `json_decode` will make it return an associative array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks, I did like you. I built an object instead of an array and I've used `JSON.stringify` and in my php I've used `json_decode`. Everything is working perfectly, Tanks alot.

Comment: +1 for the sample and the detail on both sides . . . would have been perfect if it explained why the previous method wasn't working . . .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can post an array like that.

Splitting it should work just fine:

```
$.post("ajax/"+action+"_xml.php",{'type': array["type"], 'name' : array["vars"]["name"],...},function(data){console.log(data);});
```

Comment: This way might not be the best considering an array with dozens of keys. (possibility)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your javascript array into a string, as that's all the [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method accepts.  Most people do this by [converting their array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-javascript-array-to-json).

Comment: Since there is nothing wrong with your answer, here's an upvote to nullify it ;)