# convert json to another json format

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to json. I am having a little trouble inconverting a json from one format to another format. 
This is my json to be converted.

```
{
    "message": "Successfully Advisor data has been fetched.",
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "dataHeaders": ["Carrier","B2B", "EM"],    
        "dataArray": {
            "DHL": ["DHL", "45", "5","5"],
            "Fedex": ["Fedex","40", "7","6"],
            "UPS" : ["UPS","30", "10","3"],
            "TNT" : ["TNT","30", "10","3"],
        }
    }
}
```

I require the json to be converted to this format.

```
[ 
 {
  "key":"Carrier",
  "values":[
     {
        "x":"DHL",
        "y":45
     },
     {
        "x":"Fedex",
        "y":40
     },
     {
        "x":"UPS",
        "y":30
     },
     {
        "x":"TNT",
        "y":35
     }
  ]
},
{

  "key":"B2B",
  "values":[
     {
        "x":"DHL",
        "y":5
     },
     {
        "x":"Fedex",
        "y":7
     },
     {
        "x":"UPS",
        "y":10
     },
     {
        "x":"TNT",
        "y":5
     }

  ]
},

{

  "key":"EM",
  "values":[
     {
        "x":"DHL",
        "y":5
     },
     {
        "x":"Fedex",
        "y":6
     },
     {
        "x":"UPS",
        "y":3
     },
     {
        "x":"TNT",
        "y":5
     }
  ]
}
]
```

How can i do this using jquery?

Comment: First of all: that's not a job for jQuery but for pure JavaScript. Secondly: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: The resulting Json is different in the matching values, you need some calculation??

Comment: [Parse the JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196), do [object/array modifications in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) and [convert the result back to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2295496/218196). If you have any specific problem with that, you can ask a question.

Comment: this output format seems rather inefficient, having an object key named "key" makes it a bit redundant, imho

Answer (score 0):

Use [var obj = jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse your input string. You can access the fields via obj.[FIELDNAME] and build your outputstring.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```
$.each(a.data.dataArray,function(){
   //use this[] with the index
});

$.each(a.data.dataHeaders,function(){
  //use this for the headers values
});
```

and construct your output object.

Answer (score 0):

As I had a little freetime during lunch I gave this a shot, this should get you going:

```
var before = {
    "message": "Successfully Advisor data has been fetched.",
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "dataHeaders": ["Carrier","B2B", "EM"],    
        "dataArray": {
            "DHL": ["DHL", "45", "5","5"],
            "Fedex": ["Fedex","40", "7","6"],
            "UPS" : ["UPS","30", "10","3"],
            "TNT" : ["TNT","30", "10","3"],
        }
    }
};


parseData = function (jsonData) {
    var result = [];
    jsonData.data.dataHeaders.forEach(function (carrier, indexHeader) {
        var el = {}
        el.key = carrier;

        el.values = []; 

        // shortcut
        dataArray = jsonData.data.dataArray;
        // generate sub elements
        for (arr in dataArray) {

            // generate element
            subEl = {};
            subEl.x = arr;
            subEl.y = dataArray[arr][indexHeader + 1];
            // add to array
            el.values.push(subEl);
        }

        // add el to result
        result.push(el);
    });
  return result;
}

var after = parseData(before);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCpg4/1/)