# How to pass an array of string using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using this ajax to pass an array of strings to another page.

This is the array on nomes.php

```
[ 'Home','A empresa','funcionarios','Quem Somos?','Historia','Inicio',]
```

This is the code, the alert doesn't work - can anyone help?

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'nomes.php',
 beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
 },
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data){
    v=data;
    alert(v);
 }
});
```

Comment: you aren't even passing any data into the ajax request. Where is your array of strings? Maybe i'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Are you trying to *retrieve* an array of strings rather than *pass* an array of strings?

Comment: Why are you doing `overrideMimeType`?

Comment: The array you show isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the PHP-array to a JSON-array.

```
<?php
    echo (json_encode($myPhpArray));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the array into JSON using stringify to pass them through. Add this to your Ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Replace arr with your JavaScript array. This needs a plugin though. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json#2295515) for more info.

Alternatively, if your array is in PHP, not in JavaScript you can echo it out directly like this:

```
data: <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass the json to the server, you can do it like :

```
var strArray = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'];
$.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'nomes.php',
 data: {strarray: strArray},
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data){
    v=data;
    alert(v);
 }
});
```

If you're trying to receive it, you need to set the header on php side :

```
header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('str1', 'str2', 'str3'));
```

Comment: If you're not actually sending JSON, then you don't need `application/j-son` (which should actually be `application/json`) in the AJAX *request*.

Comment: I copied his code, didn't even see that part, the coffee didn't kick in yet.