# How to transform an array of objects in javascript to json?

Tags: json

I have an array of objects named `collection[]`;
eg. `collection[0]={codec:"70",event:"keyup",time:"147625879"}`

Now I want to convert the whole array to json object at once.

Comment: You can use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Comment: Just took from the answer of the link: `for anyone still reading this answer, it's worth pointing out that all modern browsers include the JSON object as standard, which means that you don't need this script unless you're planning to support older browsers like IE7 or Firefox 3.0. See CanIUse for the support chart.`

Comment: @Vadorequest, of course, your remark is very important if you don't support old browsers. Thanks!