# how to convert literal array to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hello to all  i have this array

```
["..\Uploades\Product\1.jpg", "..\Uploades\Product\2.jpg", "..\Uploades\Product\30304_dz6AW8Tp.jpg"]
```

i wanna convert it to this JSON

```
            [
    {
        "image": "..\Uploades\Product\1.jpg",
        "thumb": "..\Uploades\Product\1.jpg",
        "folder": "Small"
    },
  {
      "image": "..\Uploades\Product\2.jpg",
      "thumb": "..\Uploades\Product\2.jpg",
      "folder": "Small"
  },
    {
        "image": "..\Uploades\Product\30304_dz6AW8Tp.jpg",
        "thumb": "..\Uploades\Product\30304_dz6AW8Tp.jpg",
        "folder": "Small"
    }
            ]
```

what should i do?

Comment: Convet it in js or php??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a JSON string?  Or do you just want to convert it to that structure?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes,i wana convert to JSON string

Comment: @Jain i wana convert it to JSON string in js

Comment: @user3281649 u have to try serialize method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = ["..\\Uploades\\Product\\1.jpg", "..\\Uploades\\Product\\2.jpg", "..\\Uploades\\Product\\30304_dz6AW8Tp.jpg"] ;
```

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of objects, and then [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it to get JSON:

```
var JSON = JSON.stringify(arr.map(function(x) {
    return {image:x, thumb:x, folder:'Small'};
}));
```

Don't forget to [shim Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) and [JSON.stringify](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) if you need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arr= ["..\Uploades\Product\1.jpg", "..\Uploades\Product\2.jpg", "..\Uploades\Product\30304_dz6AW8Tp.jpg"];
var json = [];
$.each(arr, function(i,v){
    json.push({"image":v,"thumb":v,"folder":"small"});
});

console.log(json);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MkGC3/1/)**