# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'serialize'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
mybook.push({
            pages: $("#id_pages").val()
           });

mybook.serialize()
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'serialize'

How to fix it?

Comment: what is `invoiceItems`

Comment: You should show how you define the variable invoiceItems.

Comment: Should you not be serializing mybook, rather than invoiceItems?

Comment: yes because this `mybook` is not a jQuery object, its an array.

Comment: But i think you can `console.log($(mybook).serialize())`

Comment: what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `mybook` is not a jQuery object,As of [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) you should pass it to jQuery Class then you can use the method `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()`

`console.log($(mybook).serialize())`

Comment: How to build JSON string from `mybook` array?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json?answertab=active#tab-top