# Convert array to json - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

```
{
   "user": {
       "name": "Test",
       "gender": "m",
       "birthday": "05.05.2014",
    },
    "work" : "programmer"
}
```

To parse the data from the form we use it:

```
angular.forEach($scope.profile, function(value, key){
```

With an array of forms comes in a format:

```
  key = {user_name: "Test"}
```

To convert to:
       key = { user : {name: "Test"}}

```
angular.forEach($scope.profile, function(value, key){
    var keyArray = key.split('.');
    if (keyArray.length > 1) {
       ????
    } else {
        res[key] = value.$modelValue;
    }
}, log);
```

Comment: What is question then?

Comment: This is already on stackoverflow, you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AngularJS functions for this

**Convert json to array:**

```
var array = angular.fromJson(yourJson);
```

**Convert array to JSON:**

```
var json = angular.toJson(yourArray);
```