# How to display this json in jquery

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I not which part I am doing wrong. I couldn't able to fetch this array to display. Can someone please help me with this. I am new to JSON.

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{"id":2,"request_id":2,"message":"wqvewq ewq wq ewq e wqwe  qwe ","user_id":1,"created_at":"2014-05-30 16:21:28","updated_at":"2014-05-30 16:21:28"},{"id":3,"request_id":2,"message":"as aS A","user_id":2,"created_at":"2014-05-30 17:18:37","updated_at":"2014-05-30 17:18:37"},{"id":4,"request_id":2,"message":"AS As a","user_id":2,"created_at":"2014-05-30 17:18:43","updated_at":"2014-05-30 17:18:43"}]
    [1] => [{"id":1,"request_id":2,"message":"sfsdfds sdfds f   ","user_id":2,"created_at":"2014-05-30 17:15:16","updated_at":"2014-05-30 17:15:16"}]
    [2] => []
)
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Comment: what produced that?  The keys are not a legal syntax for a JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you have quoted looks like PHP `print_r` output, and it's certainly not legal JSON.

Perhaps you need the PHP [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, to get real JSON out of your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not one json string but an array of json strings.
You have to first loop thru the array, parse the json and show the variables that you want in your html with jQuery.

You can find a lot of info on the internet and stackoverflow on this subject.

Comment: no, it is _not_ an array of JSON strings.  This is (mostly) a plain and simple object literal.  The keys aren't in the right syntax, though...

Comment: You probably should have tagged your post with `laravel` and `php`, then...   I expect you'll be wanting the PHP `json_encode` function to handle sending this structure over HTTP to the jQuery client, which if you're using normal jQuery code will automatically convert it back into an object structure.

Answer (score 0):

these are the possibilitys you have

```
var data = array();
for(var i=0;i<yourArray.length;i++)
    data[i] = $.parseJSON(yourArray[i]);
```

or **(untested)**

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({yourArray: yourArray}));
```

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourArray));

Comment: No problem, just finished it myself and didn't want to create a new answer.

Comment: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". This error throws off. Probably the array function at the start

Comment: @winnyboy5 if my post was helpful, don't be a shame to vote up the answere :D

Comment: I think he did, but I've downvoted because it completely missed the point - the data supplied wasn't JSON at all.

Comment: @Alnitak but as you can see, it WAS helpful for him and the quation wasn't `where is my error...` according to his question `How to display this json in jquery` my answere IS right! echoing and working with the result could help him as well