# Serialize array and put on input value

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I´m trying to serialize array created from list (ul) and include it on input value, how can i do this?

My actual code take the list element text as value and the original position.

```
<script>
     $(function () {
            $("#opciones").sortable();
            $("#opciones").disableSelection();
            updateOrder();
            $("#sortButton").click(sortClick);
        });

        $('#opciones').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function () {
            updateOrder();
        });
        function updateOrder() {
            var orderArray = [];

            $("#opciones li").each(function (i, el) {
                orderArray.push($(el).text());
                orderArray.push($("li")[i+1].className.slice(5));
            });

            $("#display").text(orderArray.join(" "));


        }

       function sortClick() {
            updateOrder();

            $("#display").text("click: " + $("#display").text());
        }
</script>
```

Comment: whats the issue here ?

Comment: I dont know how to serialize the response of this script, and send to a input value.

Comment: Well you can use `.serialize()`,ref:http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: refer this So for serializing the data in json format,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Comment: Thanks all, i was reading and trying in bad way with this example and manual i done it, i love you guys it was too simple, im ashamed for my question

Comment: Good to know .Thats ok, it happens sometimes. lets just close it with a self answer, by adding the working solution in the ANSWER section and ticking it as ANSWER(after few hours)