# How to pass array through ajax URL?

Tags: arrays, ajax, angularjs, codeigniter, url

I want to pass a PHP array as URL parameter in GET method . 
Here is my php array : Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 )

1st I convert it to angularJs array like this

```
$scope.myData.excludeList = '<?php echo JSON_encode($savedList);?>';
```

Then I pass this array like this :

```
$scope.myData = {};
$scope.myData.array =[];
var response = $http({
    url: 'http://localhost/control/file_list/', 
    method: "GET",
    params: $scope.myData.array 
});
response.success(function (data){
    $scope.list = data.list;
});
```

But when it hit the URL look like

http://localhost/control/file_list/%5%%22 lab lab lab....
how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution I think

```
var formData = {                        
                data1: val1,
                data1: val2
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

[Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

then in php

json_decode($myJsonString, true);