# How to convert array to json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like:

```
myarray['field1'] = "content of field1";
myarray['field2'] = "content of field2";
```

if I do console.log(myarray) I get:

```
myarray = [ field1 : "content of field1", field2 : "content of field2" ]
```

so I would transform to JSON so I tried to JSON.stringify(myarray) but it didn't worked... what I could have missed?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers
Luigi

Comment: First of all... its not an `array`. It is a `map` ( or `object` in JavaScript ). Second...  `JSON.stringify( whatever )` will always work as long as `whatever` is anything valid in JavaScript. What was the error that you were getting... ?

Comment: have a look at this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Comment: Is this `JavaScript` ? because your choice of identifier `myarray` for a map-like thing suggests that you are using `php`.

Comment: it's in Javascript: starting from var myarray = []; I try to do console.log(myarray) I get [field1: "content1", field2: "content2"] then I try console.log(JSON.stringify(myarray)); and I get []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself.... I had just to declare myarray as:

```
var myarray = {};
```

so everything worked in this way.
Thanks anyway to all!!
Cheers
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php function I think might work for you:
    function raw_json_encode($input) {

```
return preg_replace_callback(
    '/\\\\u([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/',
    function ($matches) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*',$matches[1]),'UTF-8','UTF-16');
    },
    json_encode($input)
);
```

}

it returns a string in JSON format.