# Save array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a long array like this:

```
var array = [{x: 0, y:0} ...];
```

Who contains almost 2000 objects.
How can I export this to text and use it in another javascript file/project?

Comment: Write it to a file on the server with PHP?

Comment: Convert it to JSON,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(array)`. This will return you with a string that you can save somewhere, say, on the server, and then re-use it as javascript array again.

To send the string to a server, you can use [jQuery's $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. To retrieve it back, you can again use the $.ajax function, but it might be a good idea to also  specify that the result from server is of type json. To do that, specify `dataType` to be `json` in the function.

Comment: `This will return you with a string that you can save somewhere, say, on the server` this is the important part, how can he do that?

Comment: "and then re-use it as javascript array": how? Perhaps edit your question to mention that.

Answer (score 8):

Try like this

```js
var array = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}];
var a = document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("a")
);
a.download = "export.txt";
a.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(JSON.stringify(array));
a.innerHTML = "download example text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringify it and copy it to another JavaScript project

```
JSON.stringify(array);
```