# Save modified ColumnDataSource

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bokeh

I'm trying to use flask and bokeh to build a web application where users can manually classify data. The UI, right now, makes use of a custom javascript callback to render changes visually, but I'm not sure how to use javascript to send a post request back to my flask app to log the user's activity.

An alternate solution that I would like to consider is to convert the `ColumnDataSource` to a `.csv` file that the user can download once they've finished with a particular page, but I'm not sure how to access the `ColumnDataSource` after the api call in flask.

I've included a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.events import DoubleTap
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN 
from flask import Flask
import numpy as np

# color map
cmap = CategoricalColorMapper(
    factors=[0, 1], 
    palette=['red', 'green']
)

# custom javascript callback
js_code = """ 
    var x = cb_obj['x'];
    var left = src.data['left'];
    var right = src.data['right'];
    var color = src.data['color'];
    for (i=0; i < left.length; i++) {
        if ((x > left[i]) && (x < right[i])) {
            var c = color[i]
            if (c < 1) {
                color[i] = 1
            } else {
                color[i] = 0
            }
        }
    }
    src.data['color'] = color
    src.trigger('change')
"""

# flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    N = 10
    left = np.arange(N)
    right = left + 1 
    color = np.random.randint(2, size=N)

    src = ColumnDataSource({
        'left': left,
        'right': right,
        'color': color
    })  

    fig = figure(
        width=500, height=200,
        title='Double Click to Change Color'
    )   
    fig.quad(
        'left', 'right', 0, 1,
        source=src,
        fill_color={'field': 'color', 'transform': cmap},
        line_color='black'
    )   

    callback = CustomJS(code=js_code, args={'src': src})
    fig.js_on_event(DoubleTap, callback)
    title = 'test'
    html = file_html(fig, CDN, title)

    return html

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sending POST requests from JS, you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST).

However, in your scenario I'd use a Bokeh server ([example of usage with Flask](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.10/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py)) - this way, you shouldn't need any manual POST requests as the `ColumnDataSource` from your example would be synched to the Bokeh server after you trigger the change signal (by the way, "trigger" is deprecated, you should use `src.change.emit()`).

In a custom GET handler, you can access any model of your Bokeh document on Bokeh server by using `get_model_by_name`:

```
@app.route('/cds-data/<cds_name>')
def get_cds_data(cds_name):
    data = curdoc().get_model_by_name(cds_name).data
    return some_dict_to_csv_string_function_you_have_to_write(data)
```

If you still don't want to use Bokeh server, you still don't need any POST requests - you can convert the data to a string and then use something like the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29534664/564509