# How to parse json object datalist in ajax sucess using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, arraylist

i am trying to parse json datalist in ajax  success bt it couldnot work. i have passed object containing list of data using json from controller to view,i help to parse json object in ajax success. i have attached my code below.

//return json object from controller

```
 PurchaseDetails pd = new PurchaseDetails();
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        pd.serialList.Add(new SerialInfo { 
                            Machine_serial_no = dr[0].ToString(), macAddress = dr[1].ToString(), isMacPresent = _TD1.CheckMac(machineTypes_MTId),brandName=obj.brandName,machineName=obj.machineName,MachineModel=obj.MachineModel,modelId=modelId,machineId=obj.machineId,brandId=obj.brandId});

                        // pd.macaddressList.Add(new MacAddressInfo { MacAddress = dr[1].ToString() });
                    }                   
                }
            }
            return Json(new {pd}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     return Json(new {pd}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

// my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Import/ImportPurchase",
    type: "POST",
    data: function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", jQuery("#file").get(0).files[0]);                                 
        data.append("machineTypes_MTId", jQuery('#machineTypes_MTId').val());
        data.append("modelId", jQuery('#searchValue').val());
        data.append("modelName", jQuery('#searchid').val());
        return data;
    }(),
    dataType:"JSON",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {                        
        alert(data.Machine_serial_no)
```

Comment: In your success callback, data is an object with a property named `serialObj` which is your list (its not clear why you don;t just use `return Json(pd, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` instead. But if `pd` is a list then you will need to loop through it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes exactly that is what i want to do bt as i am a learner i cant parse that pd object in my ajax sucess , can u help ?

Comment: You need to show what `pd` is. If its a collection, then show the model in the collection

Comment: I think your JSON object construct is wrong. It should be `return Json(new { serialObj : pd }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @Anand, No. OP's usage is correct.

Comment: @Anand i just recorrect my json object as  return Json(pd, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: @StephenMuecke 'pd' is a model object containg serial_list

Comment: Which part about _"you need to show the model"_ do you not understand? Edit your question to show what `pd` is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i 've just edit my question . hoping your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller method is returning

```
return Json(new { serialObj = pd}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

which is an object containing a name `serialObj`

So in the ajax success call back, you would need to access it using

```
success: function (data) {
  var PurchaseDetails = data.serialObj;
```

Since `PurchaseDetails` contains a collection named `serialList` which is a collection of `SerialInfo`, then to access the value of the first `Machine_serial_no`, it would be

```
var serialNo = data.serialObj.serialList[0].Machine_serial_no;
```

However it would be easier to just use

```
return Json(pd, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you then want to access each `Machine_serial_no` property in the collection, use

```
success: function (data) {
  $.each(data.serialList, function(index, item) {
    var serialNo = item.Machine_serial_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery.parseJSON() to parse ajax response to JSON.

but seeing from your code, seems the response should already be in JSON because dataType parameter is already set to "JSON".

try this:

- remove "()" after the ending bracket of function in "data" parameter.
- try to console.log(data) and look at the response from your browser console,
  the response might not be a valid json string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for convert js array to JSON then just use `JSON.stringify()` function. This will convert your JS variable `data` value to JSON format.

You can more find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json).

Comment: i want to parse json object value passing from controller to view while ajax is sucess