# Ajax won't post an array to controller

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

After setting a new data-order_item to my divs, I'm trying to post an array to my controller with the data_order and the data_id:

```
  var counter = 0;
  item_cnt = new Array(); 
  cnt.find('.item_incompleted').each(function(){
    counter += 1;
    $(this).attr("data-order_item", counter);
    item_element = new Array();
    item_element['order'] = $(this).attr("data-order_item");
    item_element['item_id'] = $(this).attr("data-item_id");
    item_cnt.push(item_element);
  });
  url = cnt.attr('data-order_route');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: item_cnt,
  });
```

By console logging item_cnt the array is fine, however, by var_dumping $_POST in the controller the array is empty and it seems like it's not posting the array at all.

Comment: Check the network tab in the developer console and see if anything is being sent

Comment: I did and nothing is being sent, I can't figure out why though.

Comment: You must convert the array to json, before you can sent it via ajax. Then on the PHP site, you need to convert the json back. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Comment: 1. `item_element` should be an `object` and not an `array` 2. `data` has to be an object with key-value-pairs or a correctly encoded querystring

Comment: It works creating an object, thanks!