# How to modify Array of objects using JS?

Tags: javascript

I have data that contains array objects and some objects contains arrays of objects like below:

**Original :**

```
[{
        "order": 1,
        "product": "A",
        "item": "A"
    }, {
        "order": 1,
        "product": "B",
        "item": "B"
    },

    {
        "order": 14,
        "product": "C",
        "item": "C",
        "lists": [{
            "order": 1,
            "product": "C1",
            "item": "c1"
        }, {
            "order": 1,
            "product": "c2",
            "item": "c3"
        }]
    }, {
        "order": 1,
        "product": "d",
        "item": "d"
    }, {
        "order": 72,
        "product": "e",
        "item": "e",
        "lists": [{
            "order": 2,
            "product": "e1",
            "item": "e1"
        }, {
            "order": 6,
            "product": "e2",
            "item": "e2"
        }]
    }, {
        "order": 1,
        "product": "e3",
        "item": "e3"
    }
]
```

I want to change the data like array of objects same as below,

**Modified:**

```
[{
    "order": 1,
    "product": "A",
    "item": "A"
}, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "B",
    "item": "B"
}, {
    "order": 14,
    "product": "C",
    "item": "C"

}, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "C1",
    "item": "c1"
}, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "c2",
    "item": "c3"
}, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "d",
    "item": "d"
}, {
    "order": 72,
    "product": "e",
    "item": "e"

}, {
    "order": 2,
    "product": "e1",
    "item": "e1"
}, {
    "order": 6,
    "product": "e2",
    "item": "e2"
}, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "e3",
    "item": "e3"
}]
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: IMHO actually, JSON is mainly used to represent a set of values and not to manipulate them. Yes, what you want to is doable but it would be more convenient to do all re-arrangements in your computing layer (PHP, Ruby, Python) and get the JSON string ready to present/render.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check for `lists` and concat a new array with the actual values and the `lists` items, otherwise take the actual element.

```js
var data = [{ order: 1, product: "A", item: "A" }, { order: 1, product: "B", item: "B" }, { order: 14, product: "C", item: "C", lists: [{ order: 1, product: "C1", item: "c1" }, { order: 1, product: "c2", item: "c3" }] }, { order: 1, product: "d", item: "d" }, { order: 72, product: "e", item: "e", lists: [{ order: 2, product: "e1", item: "e1" }, { order: 6, product: "e2", item: "e2" }] }, { order: 1, product: "e3", item: "e3" }],
    flat = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.lists && [{ order: a.order, product: a.product, item: a.item }].concat(a.lists) || a);
    }, []);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the array, then check if it has a list key or not, if it has then concatenate the list in the new array and delete the `lists` key and push the element itself otherwise just directly push the element.

```
var parsedData = [];
// Iterate through data array
data.forEach(function(el) {

  // If it doesnt have a list key directly push the element
  if (!el.hasOwnProperty("lists"))
    parsedData.push(el);

  // If it has a list key
  else {
    // Concat the list to the parsedData
    parsedData = parsedData.concat(el.lists);
    delete el.lists;
    // And push current item after deleting the list.
    parsedData.push(el);

  }

});
```

**Live Code**

```js
var data = [{
    "order": 1,
    "product": "A",
    "item": "A"
  }, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "B",
    "item": "B"
  },

  {
    "order": 14,
    "product": "C",
    "item": "C",
    "lists": [{
      "order": 1,
      "product": "C1",
      "item": "c1"
    }, {
      "order": 1,
      "product": "c2",
      "item": "c3"
    }]
  }, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "d",
    "item": "d"
  }, {
    "order": 72,
    "product": "e",
    "item": "e",
    "lists": [{
      "order": 2,
      "product": "e1",
      "item": "e1"
    }, {
      "order": 6,
      "product": "e2",
      "item": "e2"
    }]
  }, {
    "order": 1,
    "product": "e3",
    "item": "e3"
  }
];

var parsedData = [];
// Iterate through data array
data.forEach(function(el) {

  // If it doesnt have a list key directly push the element
  if (!el.hasOwnProperty("lists"))
    parsedData.push(el);

  // If it has a list key
  else {
    // Concat the list to the parsedData
    parsedData = parsedData.concat(el.lists);
    delete el.lists;
    // And push current item after deleting the list.
    parsedData.push(el);

  }

});

document.write(JSON.stringify(parsedData));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This snippet might help you.**

```js
var data = [{
        "order": 1,
        "product": "A",
        "item": "A"
    }, {
        "order": 1,
        "product": "B",
        "item": "B"
    },

    {
        "order": 14,
        "product": "C",
        "item": "C",
        "lists": [{
            "order": 1,
            "product": "C1",
            "item": "c1"
        }, {
            "order": 1,
            "product": "c2",
            "item": "c3"
        }]
    }, {
        "order": 1,
        "product": "d",
        "item": "d"
    }, {
        "order": 72,
        "product": "e",
        "item": "e",
        "lists": [{
            "order": 2,
            "product": "e1",
            "item": "e1"
        }, {
            "order": 6,
            "product": "e2",
            "item": "e2"
        }]
    }, {
        "order": 1,
        "product": "e3",
        "item": "e3"
    }
];


var newObj = [];

data.forEach(function (val) {
  if(val.hasOwnProperty("lists")) {
    var lists = val.lists;
    
    delete val["lists"];
    
    newObj.push(val);
    
    lists.forEach(function (valList) {
      newObj.push(valList);
    });
  } else {
    newObj.push(val);
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```