# Making an object from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am using Node and scrapping a website and I get the data back it comes back as a string so I make an array out of the string and the array look like below

I have an array that looks like this:

```
`[ [ '2011\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2010\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2009\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2008\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2007\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2006\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2005\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2004\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2003\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '2002\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '2001\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '2000\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1999\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1998\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1997\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1982\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1981\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1980\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1979\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1978\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1977\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1976\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1975\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1974\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1973\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1967\r\n', '15"', '15"' ],
  [ '1966\r\n', '15"', '15"' ],
  [ '1965\r\n', '15"', '15"' ],
  [ '1964\r\n', '15"', '15"' ] ]
`
```

I would like to make an object out of this array that looks like this

```
      var car = [
        {
        "year": 2011, 
        "driver_side": '24"',
        "pass_side": '21"'
        },
        {
        "year": 2010, 
        "driver_side": '24"',
        "pass_side": '21"'
        },
        {
        "year": 2009, 
        "driver_side": '24"',
        "pass_side": '21"'
        },
        {
        "year": 2008, 
        "driver_side": '24"',
        "pass_side": '21"'
        },
        {
        "year": 2007, 
        "driver_side": '22"',
        "pass_side": '20"'
        },

        // And so on...........
  ]
```

Any Help? That is what I need thank you for any help

Comment: go to this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Comment: Loop through the array and pass the inner array items as values to objects, then push that object to your array on each iteration.

Comment: @DanielMendes That's not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array = [ [ '2011\r\n', '24"', '21"' ] /* etc. */ ];

var cars = array.map(function (item) {
    return {
        year: parseInt(item[0], 10),
        driver_side: item[1],
        pass_side: item[2]
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array is called `a`, all you need is:

```
a.map(([year,driver_side,pass_side])=>({year, driver_side, pass_side}))
```

Actually, since you wanted years to be numbers, you have to tweak it just a little:

```
a.map(([year,driver_side,pass_side])=>({year: +year.trim(), driver_side, pass_side}))
```

If you are *starting with a JSON string*, call `JSON.parse` on the string to get a JavaScript array object, then use the expression above.

Comment: And shorthand object key expressions

Comment: @Lucero: Just curious, why?

Comment: Being a Q&A site, people not using Node but another environment (e.g. browser) might find this answer, and they might wonder why the code does not run reliably (e.g. different versions of browsers).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [ [ '2011\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2010\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2009\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2008\r\n', '24"', '21"' ],
  [ '2007\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2006\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2005\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2004\r\n', '22"', '20"' ],
  [ '2003\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '2002\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '2001\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '2000\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1999\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1998\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1997\r\n', '22"', '19"' ],
  [ '1982\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1981\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1980\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1979\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1978\r\n', '18"', '18"' ],
  [ '1977\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1976\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1975\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1974\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1973\r\n', '16"', '16"' ],
  [ '1967\r\n', '15"', '15"' ],
  [ '1966\r\n', '15"', '15"' ],
  [ '1965\r\n', '15"', '15"' ],
  [ '1964\r\n', '15"', '15"' ] ]

const cars = []

for (const a of data) {
    cars.push({
        year: Number(a[0]),
        driver_side: a[1],
        pass_side: a[2]
    })
}

console.log(cars)
```