# Convert an array javascript in json

Tags: javascript, json

How can I convert an array javascript in JSON?

```
[{
    "userName": "Rodrigo",
    "date": "25 de abril de 2017",
    "score": 5
}]
[{
    "userName": "Jon",
    "date": "24 de abril de 2016",
    "score": 4
}]
```

Error: Parser error on line 5

My code

```
var result = [];
var allInfo = {
    userName,
    date,
    score
 };
 result[i] = allInfo;
 return JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: Wait, what? Shouldn't _in_ be _to_?

Comment: This is already a JSON array....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Comment: To me it looks like two Arrays consisting of one object each. Is that really what you have in your script?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the example you provided was invalid, and you want to convert a JavaScript object to JSON, use `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
var test = [{
    "userName": "Rodrigo",
    "date": "25 de abril de 2017",
    "score": 5
}, {
    "userName": "Jon",
    "date": "24 de abril de 2016",
    "score": 4
}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```