# Send an array with objects to php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

i tried here a lot of options to send data from jQuery to php but without success, i'm trying to send an array of objects like here:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "sendCartDetails.php",
            data: {
                'details': prod
            }
    });
```

where prod has this structure:

```
prod: [{name: 'Some Name'}, {name: 'Other Name'}]
```

and my php file:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['details']);

$to = "email@email.com";
$subject = "New Order";
$headers = "From: Some ";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . $data . "</td></tr>"
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

and data here it's undefined also had the 500 (Internal Server Error) when trying to send it. How to get the data correctly here? Thanks a lot

Comment: use `JSON.Stringify(prod)` in sending data then do `json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['details']), true)`

Comment: first of all check that your data is goint to the page or not (print out data in php page and check your browser console that it printing something or not?)

Comment: @guradio i did that, still not working, the same 500 error

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks, let me try

Answer (score 0):

try prod:[{"name": "Some Name"}, {"name": "Other Name"}]

Answer (score 0):

You can not send emails from localhost(your local system), unless you are using 3rd party email solution 
This Line : 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
will work on server but on local machine, it will result a 500 server error

Comment: Sending that not from localhost, this is an real server

Comment: Haha, ok Then First of all, use real json , [{name: 'Some Name'}, {name: 'Other Name'}]  is not json, and if you have a javascript array, You have to convert your array in json , please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Answer (score 0):

I believe that solution for your problem lies on server side, not on client. Also you should send data to server properly like (something like this):

```
data: {
    'details': JSON.Stringify(prod)
}
```

And check is data properly sent, you can do that in browser's development tools (on most of them is key F12) and look in Network tab.

After that, I suggest that you try to debug your PHP code, e.g.

```
die(var_dump($_POST['details']));
```

On start of your script. If this turns to undefined index notice, there is problem with sending/receiving data.