# Convert array of strings to objects and assign specific key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert the following array of strings:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

to an array of JSON objects with a specific key of, for instance, number, as follows:

```
[
    {
        number: 'one'
    },
    {
        number: 'two'
    },
    {
        number: 'three'
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Comment: That's just an array of objects, not JSON. Iterate the array, and `.push({number:item});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over all the elements in the `array` and create a new one while converting them to an `object` with the structure you need.

You can use [ES6](http://es6-features.org) to do it with fewer lines of code, but I have also provided a version with ES5:

```js
// ES6:

const arrayOfObjectsES6 = ["one", "two", "three"].map(number => ({ number }));

console.log(arrayOfObjectsES6);

// ES5:

var listOfObjectsES5 = ["one", "two", "three"].map(function(value) {
 return { number: value };
});

console.log(listOfObjectsES5);
```

Then, you can just use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get the JSON `string` representation of it:

```
JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjectsES6);
```

If you want to be able to reuse this functionality using keys other than `"number"`:

```js
function getArrayOfObjectsES6(values, key) {
  return values.map(value => ({ [key]: value }))
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(getArrayOfObjectsES6(["one", "two", "three"], 'ES6')) );

function getArrayOfObjectsES5(values, key) {
  return values.map(function(value) {
    var obj = {};
    
    obj[key] = value;
    
    return obj;  
  });
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(getArrayOfObjectsES6(["one", "two", "three"], 'ES5')) );
```

Note you can also use a regular `for`, but I think `map()` is the cleaner and most concise option here.