# get result in JSON format

Tags: node.js, javac

I have below array

```
[['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['5','4','3'],['1','2','3']]
```

How do I covert to get this in JSON format  in Javascript/Node.

```
{
"a": ['1','5','1'],
"b": ['2','4','2'],
"c" :['3','3','3']
}
```

I tired with iterating with for loop but that is for fixed no of values what if values are keep on varying for e.g. ﻿﻿

```
 [['a','b','c','d'],['1','2','3','6'],['5','4','3','7'],['1','2','3',2']]
```

or

```
[['a','b'],['1','2'],['5','4'],['1','2']]
```

Not able to get any clue ? Any help or clue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function convertArrayToJSON(arr) {
    var result = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        result[arr[0][j]] = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            result[arr[0][j]].push(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

convertArrayToJSON([['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['5','4','3'],['1','2','3']]);
```