# Convert array with special character to string

Tags: javascript

i have the below array:

```
let arr= ["5,5", "Orange", "6,1"];
```

Every item in that arr is random string and contains any character (`","`,`";"`,...")

For some reasons, i have to convert `arr` to string.

I used `let s = arr.toString()` and got the string: `s= "5,5,Orange,6,1"`

The problem is: I have to convert that string back to the array without reusing `arr` and losing the format. If i use `string.split(",")`, the result is `["5", "5", "Orange", "6", "1"]` instead of `["5,5", "Orange", "6,1"]`

i know `toString()` is the same to join array with `","`, but if i use `arr.join()` with other character then `split()`, it seems silly because item in arr is random and can contain any character.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Encode it as JSON then …

Comment: That's what JSON is for: instead of converting the array to a plain string, which can cause issues due to ambiguous use of the `,` separator in the array items, use `JSON.stringify` to convert your array to JSON and then you can always parse it back to an array using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what JSon is for.

```js
let arr= ["5,5", "Orange", "6,1"];

let arrStr = JSON.stringify(arr);

console.log('arrStr: ', arrStr, 'as string');

let newArr = JSON.parse(arrStr);

console.log('newArr:', newArr);
```