# Convert array to JSON object using JS

Tags: javascript, json

help please with converting array to JSON object

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 
var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, array));
var stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);
 
console.log(stringToJsonObject);
```

I try this and get:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

Expected result

```
{place0: 1, place1: 2, place2: 3, place3: 4}
```

Comment: Where's that "place" stuff coming from? And you result looks like a Javascript object, no JSON text involved.

Comment: Maybe here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295496/convert-array-to-json

Comment: ''place" can obviously be treated as a constant keyword

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 

var res = array.reduce((acc,item,index) => {
  acc[`place${index}`] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});
 
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const jsonObj = {}
array.forEach((v,i) => jsonObj['place'+i] = v);
console.log(jsonObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get all the array elements as a sequence of keys and values, then use `map()` to concatenate the keys with `place`, then finally use `Object.fromEntries()` to turn that array back into an object.

There's no need to use JSON in the middle.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 
var object = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(array).map(([key, value]) => ['place' + key, value]));
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Just another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using for of loop and accumulating into the object

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const result = {}
for (let item of array) {
  result['place' + item] = item;
}
console.log(result)
```